# Superposition of two wave functions of different Hilbert spaces

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, superposition

I am trying to think of this problem for quite some time. Let's say, we have two sets of wave functions $\lbrace|\psi\rangle\rbrace$ and $\lbrace|\phi \rangle\rbrace$ and they belong to two different Hilbert spaces. That is,

$$\hat{H_1}|\psi\rangle=E_1|\psi\rangle$$

and

$$\hat{H_2}|\phi\rangle=E_2|\phi\rangle.$$

In the real space $\bf{R}$, their functional domains are disjoint. That is, if  $\psi(x)$ is defined in $x\le0$, $\phi(x)$ is defined in $x>0$.

In this case, is it possible to conceive some kind of superposition between the two waves? If so, how? I mean how do we define the superposed wave function and what can be said about the energy? This paper introduces such a concept

http://dx.doi.org/10.1119/1.18854

Comment: In quantum field theory, there is a field in spacetime. But in nonrelativistic quantum mechanics, a wavefunction is not a function from $\mathbb R^3$ into the complex numbers, a wave function is a function from the  configuration space of the system into the joint spin state of the system.

Comment: Where in the cited paper does it mention having two distinct Hilbert Spaces? It's a method of images solution to reflection off an infinite potential barrier.

Comment: @Timaeus Isn't the wave function in quantum mechanics defined as $f_{\psi}\colon x\to \langle x|\psi\rangle$, and thus exactly a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to the complex numbers?

Comment: @GennaroTedesco Most definitely not. It is a function from configuration space into a joint spin state. The joint spin state is a tensor product of single particle spin states (one for each particle) and configuration space is $\mathbb R^{3n}$ when there are $n$ particles.

Comment: How would you then define the wave function for the free spinless particle, according to that definition? Can you address me to some literature to check that? I have somehow never encountered such definition before.

Comment: @Timaeus: right...it's a method of images solution. But the image wave should be confined at $x>0$ (as depicted in the paper), because it is subjected to inverted potential $V(x)=0\ \forall x>0$ and $V(x) \rightarrow\infty\ \forall x\le0$. Notice that the potential seen by the image state is different from the potential seen by the physical state $\psi(x)$. Strictly speaking, theie Hamiltonians are different and that means the Hilbert spaces of the physical & the images states are also different (though $\frac {d^2}{dx^2}$ remains the same under $x\rightarrow-x $).

Comment: The potential seen by the physical state is $V(x)=0\ \forall x\le0$ and $V(x)\rightarrow\infty\forall x>0 $. Therefore, simple addition of these two states seems little oversimplification to me. Well, it may happen that if we extend the Hilbert space (as said by user3257624), the final result may be the simple addition. But I want to understand that clearly. It seems to me that the two states are also correlated (entangled? I do not know the definition of quantum entanglement, so cannot really say it). Is my point clear?

Comment: @GennaroTedesco A spin n/2 particle generally has a single particle spin state of $\mathbb C^{n+1}$ and so spin 0 gives a spin state of $\mathbb C^1$ which when tensored with other spin states doesn't really change the state and if you have one particle or all the particles are spin zero just gives $\mathbb C.$ surely any text says a single particle has $\mathbb C$ for spin 0, $\mathbb C^2$ for spin 1/2 and $\mathbb C^3$ for spin 1 and that you tensor them together for a joint spin state. And surely they all say the domain is configuration space. And don't forget the @

Comment: @kolahalb You do the method of images by replacing the potential with a free particle and make the function odd which then enforces that it is zero at the origin for all time under the free particle Hamiltonian. The only trick then is similar to an EM image problem you only integrate outside the zero field region to find the actual physical energy, but you get the solution and the dynamics from the combination of real and image solution. So you use the free particle Hamiltonian to evolve, but when you compute the actual energy only integrate over $x<0.$

Comment: This entirely like a charge above a conducting grounded slab that fills half of space (where $x>0$). Instead of having a fixed potential in that half space you make an image solution in that half space then take the actual and image solution and evolve away, Sometimes keeping in mind that the actual energy on exists on half the space. Every objection you raise could be equally applied to that EM example. And entanglement isn't going to fix it. And tensoring isn't going to fix it. Because those assume you already solved the original problem so that defeats the purpose of the method of images.

Comment: But don't you agree that the two wave functions belongs to different Hilbert spaces?

Comment: In electrostatics, we can simply use the principle of superposition. If $V_1({\bf r})$ & $V_2({\bf r})$ individually satisfies Laplace's equation, then $a\ V_1({\bf r})+b\ V_2({\bf r})$ will also do the same. But in this problem, the equations satisfied by the real and the image state are intrinsically different. How can we possibly add them? Perhaps the final result in the paper is correct, but I guess some internal steps are missing.

Comment: I am getting a message that we should better resort to chat window instead of extending the discussion here. So, can we go that way?

Answer (score 2):

Two different Hibert spaces correspond to two different physical systems. Superposition of wave functions makes sence for one system (for one Hilbert space), since addition of vectors (quantum states) is defined in a particular vector space (Hilbert space). What you can do is to create a new Hilbert space by forming the tensor product of the two Hilbert spaces. And if you work in the coordinates representation, then you should expand the domain of the each wave function to the entire real line, by multiplying $\psi \left( x \right)$ whith the characteristic function of $\left( -\infty ,0 \right]$ and $\varphi \left( x \right)$ with the characteristic function of $\left( 0,+\infty  \right)$.

Comment: In such a case, what will happen to the inner product of the new Hilbert space !

Comment: If by saying "what will happen?" you mean "how is it defined?", then check this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_Hilbert_spaces

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I shall go through this concept. One query: in the extended Hilbert space, does the two wave functions add normally? or do we need to construct some direct product or direct sum?

Comment: In the tensor product space, the states are products of the wave functions; what is added there is such products of them and not the individual wave functions

Comment: you are very welcome!

Comment: Hi, I started reading the concept of tensor product of spaces from Le Bellac's book. However, can you tell me how to find the characteristic function of the domain of a function? Is this function related to the metric of the space in some manner?

Comment: In these case they would be Heaviside step functions. But, on second thought, you may not need them.

Comment: Actually, after taking a look at the paper, you don't need to consider tensor products since there haven't been introduced two different Hilbert spaces; you have only one Hilbert space. It is the geometrical space (1-D space, the real line) that is splitted in two disjoint spaces (not the space of quantum states) and your physical entity lies on the left one. What this paper actually explains is that you can solve the problem of a bouncing wave-packet by considering the interference of the actual packet with it's hypothetical image propagating in the opposite direction

Comment: But how can the virtual image state (whose domain is restricted in $x>0$) be 'seen' from the space of the physical state (at $x<0$)? I am saying this, because the image state is a solution to a ${\it different}$ TISE. You could superpose them at $x<0$ if both real state and the image state were solutions to the same TISE. Isn't it? In this specific case, $\frac{d^2}{d x^2}$ remains invariant under $x\rightarrow -x$, and the general solution can be written as a linear sum at $x\le0$. But what if we were to deal with an infinite spherical barrier? Then, perhaps we cannot skip tensor product.

Comment: Tensor product is usefull when you have two different physical systems and you want to find a new Hilbert space describing both; it is not the form of your geometrical space that dictates its use. You could also apply the same method there, I suppose. This method is that you forget about the barier and see what happens when the two waves (the actual one and its image) collide and interfere at x<0. The author claims that the result is that same as if you had just one wave, which bounces back at x=0 and then interferes with its self, since the bouncing one will be like the image crossing x=0

Comment: Regarding this problem, I can see the result found by the author is absolutely fine. Yes, we 'forget' the barrier and let the physical wave and the image wave (two different physical systems - not because they are geometrically separated, but because they satisfy $\it different$ TISE) interfere near $x<0$. Doesn't that mean we are "extending" the spaces of the wave functions? If we denote the Hilbert space by $D$, don't we have $D_{new}=D_{real}\otimes{D_{ image}}$?

Comment: Not really, the are not geometrically seperated according to this method. While the physical probelm does indeed restrict the actual wave-packet to x<0, with this method you consider that both the actual and the image live on the whole real line, therefore they satisfy the same TISE. Since (by relfelction symmetry) both waves are solutions of the same TISE, what you do next is to consider a superposition of the actual wave-packet with its image and let them propagate (in opposite directions) until they collide and interfere. Then you focus on what happens for x<0.

Comment: Your confusion may be due to the follwing:

1) in eq. (1) the statement x<0 does not mean that Ψ(x,t) lives on the space x<0 but that this wave-function (which is defined on the whole real line) reproduces the actuall physical problem when we consider it for x<0; what happens for x>0 we don't care, since our actual physical system lives on x<0.

2) on statement b), the fact that ψ(-x,0)=0 comes from the fact that the actual wave-packet originaly (t=0) is non-zero only for x<0 (x<0 implies that -x>0, so ψ(-x,0) is calculated for x>0 where, by assumption, is zero)

Comment: Hi user3257624, I appreciate that you took very good care and time for explaining the point. But I think I understood the content of eq.(1) and statement b) in the paper and agree with what you said on this. I was not confused there. Of course once the method is implemented, we have the same TISE and both the real state and the image wave live in $(-\infty,\infty)$. But to start with, how do we know if the method can be used? My guess is that using the method of image here effectively means creating $D_{new}=D_{real} \otimes D_{image}$. I wanted to clarify this point only. Am I clear?